# Tree map function in Scheme

Tags: recursion, dictionary, scheme, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote 90% of a tree-map function in scheme, but I encountered a major problem that I am having trouble with. When I test my code with binary tree, all but the first node gets mapped properly. The first node drops out, and I can't seem to think of a way around this. Any advice here as would be appreciated.

```
(define (value tree)
 (car tree))

(define (left tree) 
  (car (cdr tree)))

(define (right tree)
 (car (cdr (cdr tree))))

(define (tree-map f T)
 (cond ((null? T) '())
     ((and (null? (right T))(null? (left T))) '())                                                              
     ((and (null? (right T))(not (null? (left T))))
                    (make-tree (f (value(left T)))
                               (tree-map f (left T))
                               (right T)))
     ((and (null? (left T))(not (null? (right T))))
                    (make-tree (f (value(right T)))
                               (left T)
                               (tree-map f (right T))
                               ))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is really convoluted. First I don't see an else statement, and a pretty big case drop (if both branches are not null tress). Second why are you worrying if the left or right is null when you have a case already for null trees?

```
(define (tree-map f T)
 (cond ((null? T) '())
       (else (make-tree (f (value T))
                        (tree-map f (left T))
                        (tree-map f (right T))))))
```

Being a human compiler is no fun. All you've don with you leaf, empty-left, and empty-right cases is rewrite the same code, but manually drop in the '() where appropriate instead of relying on the function to do it for you.

Comment: Sometimes we think too hard, don't we?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are a couple of errors:

- If a leaf node is found, you aren't applying the function to that node
- The case where a node has both subtrees is missing
- The part where the function is applied is wrong

Try this with one of your samples, the question doesn't include all the necessary code to test it myself:

```
(define (tree-map f T)
         ; empty tree
  (cond ((null? T)
         '())
         ; leaf node
        ((and (null? (right T)) (null? (left T)))
         (make-tree (f (value T)) '() '()))
         ; empty right subtree
        ((and (null? (right T)) (not (null? (left T))))
         (make-tree (f (value T))
                    (tree-map f (left T))
                    '()))
         ; empty left subtree
        ((and (null? (left T)) (not (null? (right T))))
         (make-tree (f (value T))
                    '()
                    (tree-map f (right T))))
         ; both subtrees are present
        (else
         (make-tree (f (value T))
                    (tree-map f (left T))
                    (tree-map f (right T))))))
```

Comment: Success! By the way, the reason I didn't provide the function for creating the tree is that it is a little bit long. If you think I should add it to this post, let me know.